# delay the loading of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview

Hi I am getting the information from the server in view did load. Since this is web service the data retrieval is in another thread making the main thread continue and call:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

before the data is populated. Is there a way to make the main thread wait for the results or to load the table once the data is retrieved?

Thanks

Comment: Did you call `tableView.reloadData()` once you get the data from server?

Comment: you need GCD(Grand Central Dispatch). post your codes on retrieving data from server.